# Web application Bad Request

Tags: javascript, java, spring, hibernate, jsp

I have a web application which uses Spring and Hibernate.

Sometimes I get the following message in browser when I try to access my web application:

```
Bad Request: Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.
```

Same url works after, I clear all my cookies from browser. I ain't able to figure out what happens and why did i get this bad request ? I tried to search for concrete solution but couldn't find any.

Comment: Use chrome or firefox network panel to intercept the request, and add it to your post.

Comment: It helped me. Thanks alot.